# Facebook api - is it possible to consult data from other users' pages?

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Good afternoon, I was asked to do some research on the possibility that Facebook api da for us developers. However, I already noticed that the actions are very limited and the majority only for our own user and pages. So I would like to know if someone with more knowledge in this area could ask me a question. Is it possible for me with my app, to browse other users to get the page that he owns and make tanned queries on the page and so on?

Comment: If the other user granted you permission yes. Otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

See Page Public Content Access feature

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference/page-public-content-access/